# Small part for Shimano 105 brakes

Tags: brakes, shimano, parts

My road bike has Shimano 105 brakes, circa 2003. Today, I removed the shoes from the front brakes, unscrewed the "fixing screws", and slid out the pads, so I can put in new pads.

Somehow, for one of the shoes, I misplaced the small part that sits inside the shoe, in front of the pad, that has the threads to receive the screw that mounts the shoe to the brake. I've scoured for it, couldn't find it.

Any idea where I might find such a part?

Comment: The part showed up (in the kitchen sink). So never mind!

Comment: Not an answer, but the "shoes" are not part of the brake calipers.  Instead, you could have bought some new cartridge holders (what you called shoes) and brake pads.  The phrase "brake shoe" is the main wear part of a drum brake system and presses radially-outward.  A "brake pad" presses sideways/across into a rotor or rim, and a historic "brake spoon" presses on the outside edge of the wheel.

Comment: Some makes of after-market brake pads are sold with those small retaining screws included, as people tend to lose them or the hex heads get messed.

Comment: I'm closing this as "off topic" cos none of the options really suit.  Good work finding your missing part!

Comment: Very specialised question already resolved by OP.  No chance of wider audience relevance.